# What is a good firewall for windows that can block packets based on tcp flags?

Tags: firewall, windows-firewall, packet

I need to find a good firewall for windows that i can use to block packets based on their tcp flags.  In this case for example, i need to block incoming FIN packets.

Does anyone have a firewall to suggest?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [WIPFW](http://wipfw.sourceforge.net/) or [PKTFILTER](http://www.hsc.fr/ressources/outils/pktfilter/).